# The array is not reversing

Tags: java

According to this piece of code I must get a reverse array but I'm still getting the non-reversed.

```
public class Reversing_array {
    public static void reverse_arr(int arr[]) {
        int n = arr.length - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[n - i];
            arr[n - i] = temp;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
        reverse_arr(arr);
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I performed a dry run of it, but still didn't reached to the mistake.

Comment: For further refrence, learn to use a debugger or to add debug prints to your code. By writing out the elements being swapped in the loop you would have spotted the mistakte much faster than what it took to write a stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an array of four elements, and run swaps four times:

```
1 2 3 4 // initial state
4 2 3 1 // first swap
4 3 2 1 // second swap <- this is what we want
4 2 3 1 // third swap  <- but we kept going...
1 2 3 4 // fourth swap <- and going...
```

You want to swap `arr.length / 2` times to avoid *re*-swapping back into the original order. If the length of the array is odd, this will avoid swapping the middle element, but that's okay.

Answer (score 1):

When you swap your complete array, so in first half of swap, you elements of first half array are swapped with second half.

And in second half of swap, first half of array is again replaced with second half of array.

As the result, you get same output as input.

So here we just need to swap for half of array length.

```
public class Reversing_array {
    public static void reverse_arr(int arr[]) {
        int n = arr.length - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length/2; i++) { // Here is the change
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[n - i];
            arr[n - i] = temp;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
        reverse_arr(arr);
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When swapping the elements of the array, we should only iterate through half of the array otherwise we would end up with swapping twice.
So need to swap till **i<n/2;**
Try this code:

```
public class Reversing_array {
    public static void reverse_arr(int arr[]) {
        int n = arr.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) {
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[n - i - 1];
            arr[n - i - 1] = temp;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
        reverse_arr(arr);
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What was the problem? How does this fix it? Elaboration would improve this answer.

Comment: Updated with problem and solution :) @Chris